# Python Django How to Create Hash Fields inside django models.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-model-field

I'm working on a Python(3.6) & Django(1.10) project in which I need to save some user credentials of the third party services like username, password, and email, I'm implementing only rest API, so there's no **form.py** at all.
So, How can I make hash fields inside **models.py** file?

Here's my current **models.py**:

```
class DeploymentOnUserModel(models.Model):
    deployment_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, )
    credentials = models.TextField(blank=False)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    project_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    cluster_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    zone_region = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    services = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=services)
    configuration = models.TextField(blank=False)
    routing = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.id and self.services == 'Multiple' and not self.routing:
            raise ValidationError("You must have to provide routing for multiple services deployment.")
        super().save(**kwargs)
```

I want to add three new hash fields like **username**, **password** & **email**.

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use standard `CharField`. To store hash value use [`make_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password) method before saving:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

password = models.CharField(max_length=256)

def save(self, **kwargs):
    some_salt = 'some_salt' 
    password = make_password(self.password, some_salt)
    if not self.id and self.services == 'Multiple' and not self.routing:
        raise ValidationError("You must have to provide routing for multiple services deployment.")
    super().save(**kwargs)
```

Comment: What kind of salt can I generally use?

Comment: and Do I need to call `make_password()` method for all fields need to hashed like `email` & `username` ?

Comment: @AbdulRehman if you need this fields to be hashed then yes. As for salt you can actually not provided it to `make_password` method. In this case Django generate it automatically.

Comment: Nice. But how do you verify?

Comment: Just found how to verify https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers

Comment: **Note:** this example isn't actually setting the instance `password`. Would need to use `self.password = make_password(self.password, some_salt)`

Comment: you can avoid using a particular salt as the salt parameter is not mandatory for make_password(), this way django creates it's own salt which seems more secure to me.

Comment: you can verify using check_password() function imported from  django.contrib.auth.hashers module. You don't have to use any salt here if you haven't passed any salt at the make_password() django will use it's salt automatically.